# How to setup Session Timeout in any place of the Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, session-timeout

I would like to change `Session Timeout` of `IAppBuilder`  via Admin Back End for ASP.NET Identity configuration.

**The idea is to get rid of IIS manual resetting and just configure Session Timeout in a database.**

In other words can we access `CookieAuthenticationOptions` in different places of the ASP.NET MVC App?

Can we do it in `HomeController` for example?
Is there a way to do it?

**STARTUP.AUTH.CS**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // It goes from Database
            var sessionTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(SysConfigView.GetSysConfig().SessionTimeout);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionTimeout),
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieName = ".MyApp_Authentication",
                SlidingExpiration = true
            });

          // There is other code...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Extend timeout from code where you need it

Also if you will try to change this parameter in config it will lead to application pool restart.

> Session.Timeout = 40;

Comment: ASP.NET Identity is not using web.config to manage session timeout. And I need to keep session timeout in the database and apply it to the whole application globally in any moment.